# How i can upgrade this algorithm for finding nth smallest element

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have algorithm for finding nth smallest element, but this algorithm work not so fast as i want. How i can upgrade this algorithm? This algorithm take unsorted list, start index, end index and nth element, that you want to find.

```
public static void NthElement<T>(List<T> list, int startIndex, int nthSmallest,
    int endIndex)
{
    while (startIndex < endIndex)
    {
        int left = startIndex;
        int right = endIndex;
        T mid = list[(left + right) / 2];
        while (left < right)
        {
            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(list[left], mid) > -1)
            {
                T tmp = list[right];
                list[right] = list[left];
                list[left] = tmp;
                right--;
            }
            else
            {
                left++;
            }
        }

        if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(list[left], mid) > 0)
        {
            left--;
        }

        if (nthSmallest <= left)
        {
            endIndex = left;
        }
        else
        {
            startIndex = left + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find better help on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
        public static T NthElement<T>(List<T> list, int startIndex, int nthSmallest, int endIndex)
        {
            List<T> sublist = list.GetRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
            sublist.Sort();

            return sublist[nthSmallest - 1];
        }
```